# How to handle <br /> tags in Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I've been searching for a while now onine and just havn't been able to nail the correct answer for this one. Long story short, I'm retreiving a webpage from onine to use as my inbox. I desperately need to skip lines in between each "message" so I put 
 tags in my php. It works perfectly in a web broweser but, in my Android application, I can actually see the 
 tags as plain text. Just trying to read them as "next/new lines". Any ideas?

My method code:

```
public String getInbox(String where){

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://example.com/getInbox.php?where="+where);

            HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
            post_request.setURI(website);


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);
            //executing actual request

                        //add your implementation here
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l+nl);

            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();


return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "ERROR";

        }

        }
```

The output in a webpage:

```
eg test
eg test
eg lol
eg lol
eg testing
```

The output in android:

```
eg test<br />eg test<br />eg lol<br />eg lol<br />eg testing<br />eg
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String yourString= "test<br />eg test<br />eg lol<br />eg lol<br />eg testing<br />eg34 ernestggggg";


yourString= yourString.replaceAll("<br />", lineSep):
```

Comment: This did work. Thanks so much. Such an easy solution. `replace` and `replaceAll` is such a big difference. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Make your text appear as you show it in your web browser. For that you need to use following method:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(  " Overs Alloted "  + "<small> <small> " + "at start of innings" + "</small> </small>" ));  //Example

String s= getStringFromSoruce(parameters);  //Pass the string you need here
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

You can set text using any view. You can even remove more html tags using this.

I hope this solves your purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the html to a `Spanned` String with *any* Html included.

Answer (score 0):

check out this . replace `<br />` tag with new line `"\n"`

```
data = sb.toString();

data = data.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");

return data;
```